# Difference between if and case - ruby

Tags: ruby

This code

```
if response != Net::HTTPNoContent
   raise Exception
end
puts "OK"
```

prints an exception, whereas this code

```
case response
when Net::HTTPNoContent
   puts "OK"
else
   raise Exception
end
```

prints "OK" to the console. I'd like to know what's going on.
If you need more details, let me know.

Comment: The `case` statement uses `===` internally which is different from `==`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `response` variable is, I assume, a response object returned from using `net/http`. That object's *type* will be `Net::HTTPNoContent`.

In your first `if` variant, you are checking to see if your response object is equal to the `Net::HTTPNoContent` *class*. It's not going to be. The `net/http` library isn't going to return a class when your request is sent, it's going to return an object containing all of the information about your request's response (and will be of type `Net::HTTPNoContent`, or some other class depending on the result of the request).

In your `case` variant, however, things work a little differently. Ruby tries to be intelligent about what it does with the predicates you give each `when` branch. It will do an triple-equals (`===`) (like [`#is_a?`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/is_a%3F), in this example, though it does other things) comparison against each branch, which evaluates to true if the object in question's class is (or is descended from) the class specified in the branch (or, of course, if the object *is* indeed equal).

(In Ruby, classes are objects too, which is why you can compare `response` to the class itself, like in your `if` version, and it still make sense to the interpreter.)

So this is best explained by rewriting your `if` version:

```
if !response.is_a?(Net::HTTPNoContent)
  raise Exception
end

puts "OK"
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. I'm a little confused with ruby's syntax sometimes. Thank you very much.

Comment: It's more Ruby to write `unless response.is_a?(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example:

```
a = 'a'
if a != String
   p '-'
else
   p '+'
end

case a
when String
   p '+'
else
   p '-'
end
```

Return:

```
#=> -
#=> +
```

It means that in first example you try to check if value of some response is equal to class. When you use `case when String` it would check `if a.is_a? String`